# Drupal Superfish Mega Menu stacking down

Tags: navigation

I have superfish menu working but the megamenu part is stacking the last 2 below each other instead of beside, so there is 2 columns and the last column is positioned below the second column instead of making a 3rd column.

i have looked over my link tree many times and that is correct with the hierarchy and the contains clicked on the container links.

and the problem still occurs if i remove one column it only makes 1 column and the second below that, so it seems as the last column always goes below the column before that instead of making a new last column.

[image: as you can see the last "design" column stacks below]

So how can i make the Design column to align right beside the Webb column instead of beneath it?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! So far, you stated facts, but you didn't ask any explicit question. Please add it.

Comment: Question added and adding it here too: So how can i make the Design column to align right beside the Webb column instead of beneath it?

Comment: That's a CSS question @Timmy, not something you'll find help with here. Stack Overflow is the right place in this network for CSS questions

Comment: Perhaps it might be because IT has 4 bullet values which take up space. Webb or Design wouldn't fit underneath it at the current height of the menu.

Comment: If you are open to use an alternative, I would suggest you to use "TB Mega Menu" - https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu. It is easy to build the menu structure as you want.